# Unicode string is not working on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am getting `Lucas V\U00e1zquez` string from the server. It printed in the `UILabel` as `Lucas V&aacute;zqez`.

But the Original String is `Lucas Vázquez`. How do I get the right string?

Suggestions please!!

Comment: So, Do you want to remove special character and numbers from string?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply decode your UTF8 string

```
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithCString:[utf8String cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: I try this but it throws an error +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString'

Comment: Sometimes I'm getting this from server Lucas V&aacute;zquez it gives me error. Sometimes I'm getting this Lucas V\U00e1zquez it works fine.

Comment: Lucas V\U00e1zquez is your encoded string & my answer was for this as you asked in your question, but other one is not utf encoding you need to talk with your server guy to send you utf encoded data.